# Heroku Parse Server - MongoError: failed to connect to server

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

When I access the Parse dashboard, I cannot see the "User" option under the "Browser" tab. In addition, under the error log, it says it failed to connect to server. Could anyone help me?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Error generating response. { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:260:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:162:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' }
```

Comment: is your mongod running?

Answer (score 0):

Try

"sudo service mongodb start"

and then check it..